# IAR Linker placing of packed structures

Tags: struct, arm, alignment, iar, packed

I'm struggling with the IAR linker using packed structures.

This is a structure to be placed at an absolute position:

```
typedef __packed struct
{
    uint8_t au8Build[8];
    uint16_t u16Type;
} stMetaInfo_t;

#pragma location = ".META_INFO"
const __packed stMetaInfo_t c_stMetaInfo =
{
    .au8Build = { 0U, 0U, 0U, 0U, 0U, 1U, 2U, 3U },
    .u16Type = 0x0059U
};
```

The size of the structure is 10 bytes and I verified it using sizeof().

Linker configuration:

```
place at address mem: 0x08003FE0 { readonly section .META_INFO };
```

I'd expect the linker to put exactly 10 bytes of data at the location but I can see a size of 12 bytes (0xC) in the map file:

```
"A1":                                             0xc
  .META_INFO              const    0x08003fe0     0xc  myfile.o [1]
                                 - 0x08003fec     0xc
```

... and the toolchain creates an additional hex file that shows the 2 bytes that are being added by the linker:

```
0x08003FD0 = ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 
0x08003FE0 = 00 00 00 00 00 01 02 03 59 00 !00!00! ff ff ff ff 
0x08003FF0 = ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
```

I assume that the linker is using the classic 4-byte alignment since it's a 32-bit CPU but how can I force the linker to place only 10 bytes?
Later on, the structure should be moved at the end of a specific memory region. So I don't want to have any padding bytes.

I'm using IAR Embedded Workbench for ARM Version 8.22.

Best regards
Jay

Answer (score 0):

The extra bytes are introduced by the compiler not the linker. In the compiler, static memory has an alignment of 4-byte, which implies that each data section is padded up to a multiple of 4 bytes. This behavior can not be changed by command line switches or pragmas. The only way around it is to define the meta info structure in assembler instead of C.